# DataColumn - how to distinguish datetime or datetime2

Tags: c#, datetime, types, datacolumn, datetime2

I am having trouble identifying the type of a datetime DataColumn.

If I grab a DataTable from SQL 2008 a datetime DataColumn could be a datetime or datetime2 but there appears to be no difference when in C#.

I need to validate data prior to loading into SQL...

Any ideas?

Comment: you might be able to do something to check when reading whether the type is `SqlDbType.DateTime2`.  Is changing the database type to be datetime2 out of the question?

Comment: Yes, my solution has to assume the Sql table could have any columns and datatypes in it.  It could also be a SQL 2005 db - datetime only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to scrap using the DataColumn properties for reading a table's schema as it is inaccurate in a few places (Unique always = false, Length always = -1).

I ended up retrieving the schema definition from the Sql INFORMATION_SCHEMA views instead.

Anyone know why these properties are useless in reading a DataTable's schema?  They simply don't depict the true structure of the database table...

Answer (score 1):

The precision and range is different from DateTime to DateTime2, you can probably derive a validation from [this blog post](http://aartemiou.blogspot.com/2008/12/datetime2-vs-datetime-in-sql-server.html).

Comment: Sure, I understand the differences of the SQL datatypes.  My problem is that the C# properties of a DataColumn born from a datetime Sql column has exactly the same properties to a DataColumn born from a datetime2 Sql columm.  I need to find a way to ensure a date is valid for what could potentially be a datetime Sql columm.